# Google App Engine: Basic Django Issue

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using Django templating with Google App Engine. I'm trying unsuccessfully to print out a menu.

**The controller:**

```
menu_items = {
    'menu_items': [
        {
            'href': '/', 'name': 'Home'
        },
        {
            'href': '/cart', 'name': 'Cart'
        }
    ],
}

render('Views/menu.html', self, {'menu_items': menu_items})
# ...
def render(filename, main, template_values): 
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
    main.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

**menu.html:**

```
<ul>
    {% for page in menu_items %}
    <li><a href="{{page.href}}">{{page.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The HTML produced:

```
<li><a href=""></a></li>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
menu_items = {'menu_items': [{'href': '/', 'name': 'Home'},
                             {'href': '/cart', 'name': 'Cart'}],
              }
render('Views/menu.html', self, {'menu_items': menu_items})
```

Look at these lines carefully. menu_items (dictionary) has a key menu_items with a value having a type list. And you're passing menu_items (dict) to render, so for page in menu_items actually refers to 'menu_items' (key).

Just change your code to look like:

```
menu_items = [{'href': '/', 'name': 'Home'}, {'href': '/cart', 'name': 'Cart' }]
```

and you're done...